# Dividing Values of List By I.D that was Repeated Twice

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a class of list which compose of double for I.D and double for Balance ... 
every i.d is repeatedly twice .

```
*e.g* 
<ID, Balance> 
1, - 
1, 500 
2, - 
2, 560 
3, - 
3, 540
```

i needed to divide all balance with value of "-" to balance with value ... 
balance that has a value of "-" was supposedly the current balance for previous number . 
e.g

> for number 1... "-" was supposedly the capital balance which has value
>   of 800(just a sample of capital balance) then it should be divided into next 1 which is 500 (so it supposedly be 800/500)
>   then for number 2 ... "-" should be the last value of number1(the one
>   that has value) which is 500 (so it supposedly be 500/560)

then save values of quotient to a new class of list which has value of I.D and the new value

```
e.g:

<new class of list>
ID - Balance
1 - 1.6 (since 800/500)
2 - 0.89 (since 500/560)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see this 800 so i don't understand the logic.

Comment: its just a sample value of capital balance @TimSchmelter ... just for ID 1

Comment: What is capital balance? What does <ID, Balance> mean? It is not a list. I don't understand what you want to do? Can you rewrite it while assuming we know nothing about your problem?

Comment: @smerlung q_updated ... 800 was just a sample capital balance ... it depends on text on a combobox so you can just create a sample int also representing capitalbalance ...

Comment: ive added this line:
then save values of quotient to a new class of list which has value of I.D and the new value

Comment: So you want the Balance = new double[]{ 800.0/500.0, 500.0, 500.0 / 560.0, 560.0, 560.0 / 540.0}?

Comment: @smerlung question updated again ... sorry about that mate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand this, but why don't you use a simple loop and remember the last balance? If the list is not already ordered you not do order by id first.

Here is an example using LINQ to order it and to select only those with a value. I'm assuming that `Balance` is a `decimal?`:

```
var balancesWithValues = balances
    .Where(b => b.Value.HasValue)
    .OrderBy(b => b.ID);
var newBalances = new List<Balance>();
Balance lastBalance = balances.First();

foreach (var balance in balancesWithValues.Skip(1))
{
    Balance b = new Balance() {
        ID = balance.ID, 
        Value = lastBalance.Value / balance.Value 
    };
    newBalances.Add(b);
    lastBalance = balance;
}
```

Here is the class used:

```
class Balance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

and here the sample data:

```
var balances = new List<Balance>();
balances.Add(new Balance() { ID = 1, Value = 800 });
balances.Add(new Balance() { ID = 1, Value = 500 });
balances.Add(new Balance() { ID = 2, Value = null });
balances.Add(new Balance() { ID = 2, Value = 560 });
balances.Add(new Balance() { ID = 3, Value = null });
balances.Add(new Balance() { ID = 3, Value = 540 });
```

The result in `newBalances` is:

```
ID  1    Value  1.6 
ID  2    Value  0.8928571428571428571428571429   
ID  3    Value  1.037037037037037037037037037
```

Comment: sir just asking the time i replace value of 800 to null all of them become null ... sorry for asking this very late but how can i separate the 1st value of my list (capital balance) since in data its suppose to be null